# backbone.marionette with handlebars throwing exceptions trying to load my template

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js, marionette

here is the error thrown to my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'chain' hbs.js:282
getExternalDeps hbs.js:282
(anonymous function) hbs.js:306
xhr.onreadystatechange hbs.js:73
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: hbs!templates/reset_unnormalized2,hbs!templates/pages/login_unnormalized3,hbs!templates/reset,hbs!templates/pages/login
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout require.js:160
```

i'm using the handlebars-require-plugin and i've even tried adding "hbs" to my require shim but the result is the same.

here is my marionette view code:

```
define([
    "bootstrap", // bootstrap does not export anything, so no arg sent to our function
    "marionette", 
    "session", "events",
    "hbs!templates/pages/login"
], function( Marionette, Session, Events, LoginTemplate ){
    return Marionette.View.extend({
        template : {
            type : "handlebars",
            template : LoginTemplate
        }
    });
});
```

i have no idea what's going on here and every search i've pulled up has yielded no useful results.

what's happening?  why is this happening?  please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out.

it turns out my problem was not related to the `hbs` plugin as it was with using it, handlebars, and json2 with requirejs.

the first problem, as described above, was solved by switching out the `lodash` library with `underscore`.  i was under the impression that these two were interchangeable, but apparently that is **NOT** the case.

then i was getting errors that `"stringify" is not a function on the object null` which led me to find that `JSON` was not defined inside `hbs`.

i had to go back to my `require.config({ shim:{} })` and define json2 with an export of `JSON`

now i am not getting errors from `hbs` but i have to figure out why my view is not displaying.

here is my config code, should anyone else be interested.

```
require.config({
    // paths to required javascript files
    paths : {
        bootstrap   : "../assets/js/bootstrap.min",
        jquery      : "../assets/js/jquery.min",
        json2       : "../assets/js/json2",
        underscore  : "../assets/js/underscore.min",
        backbone    : "../assets/js/backbone.min",
        marionette  : "../assets/js/backbone.marionette.min",
        hbs         : "../assets/js/hbs",
        handlebars  : "../assets/js/handlebars",
        i18nprecompile : "../assets/js/hbs/i18nprecompile"
    },

    // "shim" will allows us to load in deps synchronously so that we do not
    // run into a situation where dependencies are not available
    shim : {
        json2       : { exports : "JSON" },
        jquery      : { exports : "jQuery" },
        underscore  : { exports : "_" },
        backbone    : {
            deps : ["jquery", "underscore", "json2"],
            exports : "Backbone"
        },
        marionette  : {
            deps : ["jquery", "underscore", "json2", "backbone"],
            exports : "Marionette"
        },
        hbs : {
            deps : ["jquery", "underscore", "json2", "i18nprecompile", "handlebars"],
            exports : "hbs"
        },
        bootstrap : { deps : ["jquery"] }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Could be that you have your args to your callback incorrectly defined? If a value does not define anything (such as bootstrap) then make it last. Right now your Marionette arg contains the undefined value of bootstrap, Session now holds Marionette etc.

```
define([
    "marionette", 
    "session", "events",
    "hbs!templates/pages/login",
    "bootstrap", // bootstrap does not export anything, so no arg sent to our function
], function( Marionette, Session, Events, LoginTemplate ){
    return Marionette.View.extend({
        template : {
            type : "handlebars",
            template : LoginTemplate
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: noted.  i will move any deps like that to the end of the list from now on.  thanks!